# Android sign in button in a fragment

Tags: java, android, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to have a google sign in button to my android application.

I googled and found quickstart tutorials and with them I created the following code.

In AndroidManifest.xml i add the following:

```
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

my fragment xml (fragment_main_menu.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.tuxin.myalcoholist.myalcoholist.myalcoholist.MainMenuActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add_drink"
    android:id="@+id/add_drink"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:onClick="addStringClickHandler" />

<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

my main menu activity contains the following code:

```
package com.tuxin.myalcoholist.myalcoholist.myalcoholist;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;


public class MainMenuActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void addCocktailClickHandler(View v) {
}




/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private SignInButton mSignInButton;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private int mSignInProgress;
    private PendingIntent mSignInIntent;
    private int mSignInError;

    private static final int STATE_DEFAULT = 0;
    private static final int STATE_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private static final int STATE_IN_PROGRESS = 2;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;


    private static final String SAVED_PROGRESS = "sign_in_progress";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container, false);
        mSignInButton = (SignInButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleApiClient();

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(SAVED_PROGRESS, mSignInProgress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            // We only process button clicks when GoogleApiClient is not transitioning
            // between connected and not connected.
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.sign_in_button:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"connecting",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    resolveSignInError();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
        // When we build the GoogleApiClient we specify where connected and
        // connection failed callbacks should be returned, which Google APIs our
        // app uses and which OAuth 2.0 scopes our app requests.
        return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API, null)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .build();
    }


    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mSignInIntent != null) {
            // We have an intent which will allow our user to sign in or
            // resolve an error.  For example if the user needs to
            // select an account to sign in with, or if they need to consent
            // to the permissions your app is requesting.

            try {
                // Send the pending intent that we stored on the most recent
                // OnConnectionFailed callback.  This will allow the user to
                // resolve the error currently preventing our connection to
                // Google Play services.
                mSignInProgress = STATE_IN_PROGRESS;
                startIntentSenderForResult(mSignInIntent.getIntentSender(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sign in intent could not be sent: "
                        + e.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Attempt to connect to
                // get an updated ConnectionResult.
                mSignInProgress = STATE_SIGN_IN;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            // Google Play services wasn't able to provide an intent for some
            // error types, so we show the default Google Play services error
            // dialog which may still start an intent on our behalf if the
            // user can resolve the issue.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"play services error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // Retrieve some profile information to personalize our app for the user.
        Person currentUser = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),currentUser.getDisplayName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + connectionResult.getErrorCode(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (mSignInProgress != STATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
            // We do not have an intent in progress so we should store the latest
            // error resolution intent for use when the sign in button is clicked.
            mSignInIntent = connectionResult.getResolution();
            mSignInError = connectionResult.getErrorCode();

            if (mSignInProgress == STATE_SIGN_IN) {
                // STATE_SIGN_IN indicates the user already clicked the sign in button
                // so we should continue processing errors until the user is signed in
                // or they click cancel.
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }

        // In this sample we consider the user signed out whenever they do not have
        // a connection to Google Play services.
        onSignedOut();
    }

    private void onSignedOut() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"signed out",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


  }
}
```

I also understood that I must have an ARM emulator of version 4.4.2 in order for good play services to work in an emulator, so I did that.. and now when I click on the google sign in button it toasts the message "connecting" and after that "play services error"

so what am I doing wrong? what am I missing ?

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

## update

Now i'm using the google api x86 image. it allowed me to choose a User to login with, and then failed with error code 4 and then "An internal error occured" toast message

do I need to sign my application first?
I still didn't quite understand how google play knows to relate the application  I registered
at console.developers.google.com. I didn't use any certificate or anything..

any ideas?

## another update

I created a new client ID based on the quickstart tutorial, I typed package com.tuxin.myalcoholist
and i copyed the SHA1 string from the keytool command (using ~/.android/debug.keystore

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
```

I still get the same results.

Comment: you must use specific emulator images, the ones tagged as "google apis"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have not installed Google APIs platform on the emulator. That is the reason you are getting the error which basically indicates the service is not available.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Install):

> Install a compatible version of the Google APIs platform. If you want to test your app on the emulator, expand the directory for
>   Android 4.2.2 (API 17) or a higher version, select Google APIs, and
>   install it. Then create a new AVD with Google APIs as the platform
>   target.

**Update 1:**
Regarding "An internal error occured" toast message, it can occur when you have copied wrong key value from keytool. Please follow the [quick start documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android#install-sdk), especially step 5.

The package name and SHA1 of your package, allows Google to link up between your app and client ID generated in console. The same information is presented while creating client id, you can see it in this [image](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/images/client-id-create-android.png).

> API requests are sent directly to Google from your clients' Android
>   devices. Google verifies that each request originates from an Android
>   application that matches the package name and SHA1 signing certificate
>   fingerprint name listed below.

**Update 2**:
After installing Google Play services, did you create a new AVD with **Google APIs** as target? If not please do it, as shown in below image. You can check whether Google Play services are available by using [isGooglePlayServicesAvailable](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29).

[image]

Comment: in console.developers.google.com I created the application name, don't I need to enter client ID or client secret somewhere for it to know what application i'm talking about ?

Comment: @ufk As per my understanding, Google verifies that each request originates from the Android application matches one of the certificate SHA1 and package names specified in the console. The Drive API I had used before, had requirement to place the app id in manifest file.

Comment: thank you for your help so far. I updated main post with current status

Comment: you are awesome :) could be it. gonna try that.

Comment: updated main post. didn't have a client id to begin with, now that I created it i get the same results.

Comment: I created AVD with Google api as target. what i did notice that the packge on the manifest is com.tuxin.myalcoholist.myalcoholist.myalcoholist and not com.tuxin.myalcoholist. changing it and testing. hopefully that's the issue

Comment: yay it was the package issue. problem resolved! thanks

Comment: @ufk Great to know that. If my answer resolved the issue, can you accept the answer?

Comment: issue is resolved :) accepted the answer. you've been such a great help! thank you for everything